# find minimum in DataFrame.index with condition

Tags: python, pandas

there are two DataFrames df1 and df2 and both have timestamps as indices and I am trying to find the nearest index of df2 to df1 under condition.

```
reference_index = df1.index[0]
index_differences = reference_index - df2.index
cond1 = index_diff >= timedelta(hours=0)
cond2 = index_diff <= timedelta(hours=1)
combined_cond = cond1 & cond2
```

how can I find the minimum in index_differences under condition `combined_cond`?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: in this case 3 and 4 are the elements i am interested in. minimum of them is 3. the index of 3 is 2. the output:2

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Series([1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6])
y = Series([False, False, True, True, False, False])
x[y].argmin()
```

Comment: this code actually works, and it is what I am doing for hours, but maybe it wouldnt work for DataFrame.index?
```reference_index = df1.index[0]```
```index_differences = reference_index - df2.index```
now, how can I find the index of the minimum in index_differences? The solution above would not work for this case.

Comment: It's good to ask your actual question in the first place. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yeh you are definitely right, didn't think DataFrame.index or Series would behave so differently. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6]
y = [False, False, True, True, False, False]


print x.index(min([i for i in x if y[x.index(i)]]))
```

You can try this.

Comment: I tried to reformulate the question, the objects are indeed the indices of pandas DataFrames'.

Comment: @user1880615 then may be you can use the idea and apply to panda DataFrame